# the AppBarLayout doesn't collapse

Tags: android, layout, androidx, android-appbarlayout

After switching to androidx the following code stopped working. The TextView below the Toolbar used to scroll with the content, but now it doesn't.Is there a solution to fix this error?

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">    
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appabr"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:title="Title" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appabr">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="2"
            android:text="@string/aritical" />
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You need **androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout**
Please check the article [link] (https://blog.mindorks.com/using-coordinator-layout-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
```

Use

```
android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
```

As your root layout